Explaining button functionality on mobile app?
I'm working on an app design for updating item prices at different department stores. Essentially, the user updates the app prices by taking a picture of the actual price and the backend processes the picture and updates the database.
The problem is that I'm not sure how to explain the "picture" button to the user. In my case, there's a button that says "Update price" that, when clicked, will display a modal popup with brief instructions and the actual button to open the camera.
Here's the idea, but I'm not sure if there are better ways of explaining this.

So my question is: is there a better way to explain this to the user? I want to assume that my users are 1) dumber than a bag of bricks, or 2) not mobile power users.
We also have a website that will have explanations, but I don't want the user to have to go to our site for an explanation on the app's camera functionality.

I can't help but think it would be just as easy to enter in the new price. Especially when the user will have to position the camera to take the picture at the right size and clarity.

A note on the side: Instead of saying "I want to assume that my users are 1) dumber than a bag of bricks", I'd prefer to state that "I want my granddad to be able to do this". Anyone who is interested in comparing prices (which seems to be general process) is likely a professional in the stuff he needs to buy.

It's more of a Comms challenge than anything else. If you could accommodate a short explainer just inside the button, it might save the user having to read the explanation every time they use your app.
For example, the button could say:

Update prices with a picture
Price will be updated automatically



First screen - Make the button label as simple as possible. "Update Price" or "New Price". Explore some ideas and test them out.
Blend your second screen and the camera together and have the description available at all times without standing in their way.

. 

I like @Adnan's proposal.
Another possibility is to show the explanation together with the "Don't show this again" checkbox, so that people can control whether they see the explanation.
